# "Copy to a new draft" makes <br> not work

Tags: html, wordpress, line-breaks

To update my employers wp website (Enfold Theme), I have been using the "Copy to a new draft" feature, editing the "new" page, and then 301 redirecting the old one to the updated one. For some reason when I do that though, it renders my `<br>`'s useless.

Below is the relevant code block:

```
<div id="bread" class="div" align ="center" style="font-weight: bold;"> 
<h1 style = "color: #c30a20;">NEMA 4X (IP66)</span><br>
<span style = "color: black; font-size: 26px;">Enclosed AC Drives
<br>
For harsh, wet & dirty environments</span></h1>
[wpseo_breadcrumb]
</div>
```

On the old page, it looks like this:

[Old Header Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0aC3.png)

On the new page, it looks like this:

[New Header Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bQSh.png)

For reference the URL for the old page is: https://bardac.com/ac-drives/nema-4x/#toggle-id-5-closed

Additional Info: We operate a mac environment (macOS Catalina, v 10.15.4) and I use Firefox Nightly browser.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: https://webhostinghero.org/preserve-line-breaks-and-formatting-in-wordpress/

Comment: @Leland this is really helpful but is there a way to do this at the page level? I'm worried about it affecting the rest of my site.

Comment: You can find this yourself, I’m quite confident, through googling things like “wpautop on specific page” Happy hunting!

Comment: Thank you for your help!